# Passar dados de um DataGridView para TextBoxes no C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Olá, estou tendo um problema e já até fiz uma pergunta parecida anteriormente, mas agora estou sendo mais específico.

Tenho dois forms, um form possui um DataGridView conectado a um Banco de Dados e o outro form servirá como edição para os dados dos registros mostrados naquele DataGridView.

Para que isso ocorra, o usuário vai selecionar uma linha com um registro do DataGridView e clicar no botão Editar, que abrirá o outro form.

Não sei como fazer a seguinte parte: preciso passar os dados dos registros que estão no dataGridView no form principal para as textBoxes do form de edição, para que seja possível a alteração desses dados.

Se alguém puder ajudar, ficarei agradecido =D
Estou usando Windows Form.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //ESTE É O FORM DA EDIÇÃO 
    public partial class frm_edit : Form
     {
         public string Nome;
         public int Idade;
     }

       // este é o evento load do form da edição
    private void frm_edit_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         txtNome.Text=Nome;
         txtIdade.Text=Idade+"";
    }


    // AQUI NO FORM ONDE ESTA A DataGridView1  NO CLICK DO BOTÃO 
     {

       frm_edit  FE=new frm_edit();

      FE.Nome= Convert.ToString(DataGridView1[0,DataGridView.CurrentRow.Index].Value);
      FE.Idade= Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView1[1,    DataGridView.CurrentRow.Index].Value);

      FE.Show();
```

os números 0 e 1 são as colunas, neste caso:

0-Nome
 1-Idade

}